# How to access URL at src attribute in the iframe?

Tags: java, iframe, selenium-webdriver, fancybox

I'm trying to sendKeys in the textfield inside form. But this form is put in the link with src attribute. Attribute src refers to that link is in frame tag.

Here's the HTML code

```
<div class="fancybox-overlay fancybox-overlay-fixed" style="width: auto; height: auto; display: block;"><div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-iframe fancybox-opened" tabindex="-1" style="width: 647px; height: auto; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 351px; opacity: 1; overflow: visible;"><div class="fancybox-skin" style="padding: 15px; width: auto; height: auto;"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner" style="overflow: auto; width: 617px; height: 277px;"><iframe id="fancybox-frame1468468198811" name="fancybox-frame1468468198811" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="auto" src="addproductgroup.aspx?q=hS9DFK23Nh8Xk29sPZN9j%2bqXSaPgqztzEsozxWSIrSbx9JdDslfYJg%3d%3d"></iframe></div><title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a></div></div></div>
```

Here is the image of the form in fancybox

[Form in fancybox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siHQ5.png)

I already use this code but it didn't work

```
WebElement tambahGroup = driver.findElement(By.id("aTambah"));
tambahGroup.click();
WebElement iframe;
iframe = driver.findElement(By.id("fancybox-frame1468468198811"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
String src = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].attributes['src'].value;", iframe).toString();
driver.get("http://member.indotrading.com/product/"+src);
WebElement namaGroup = driver.findElement(By.id("txtProdukGroup"));
namaGroup.sendKeys("Bunga Mawar");
WebElement namaGroupEng = driver.findElement(By.id("txtProductGroupEnglish"));
namaGroupEng.sendKeys("Rose Flower");
Select indukGroup = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlParent")));
indukGroup.selectByVisibleText("BUN6A");
WebElement btnSave = driver.findElement(By.id("btnAdd"));
btnSave.click();// Switching to Parent window i.e Main  
Window.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

And I found this error message

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"fancybox-frame1468468198811"} Command
>   duration or timeout: 837 milliseconds For documentation on this error,
>   please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

How could I reach textfield inside the link, because this link is in iframe tag and fancybox. Big thanks for your help.

Comment: is frame id always fixed or the number is changing?

Comment: The number is always changing. How to handle it??

Answer (score 0):

The main reason of element not able to identified is `id` isn't `constant` it keeps on changing. To handle these kind of scenarios you can take help of `regex`.

You can identify the element by using `xpaths`.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'fancybox-frame')]"));
```